# .load() next page into hidden div?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery `.load()` to load a page contents.

In the callback of this `.load()` I am loading the next pages content into a hidden `<div>` with another `.load()` function in the hope to preload the images.

I have run a couple tests, and although the alert *loaded* is displaying, the images don't appear to be being cached.

I am using `display:none` on the `<div id="hidden" />` that the second `.load()` is loading into. Could this be why? If so, how can I get around this?

```
$(document).on('click', '.next', function() {

    var prevUrlTitle = $('#prev-url-title').val();
    var nextUrlTitle = $('#next-url-title').val();

    var path = '/portfolio/embed-image/'+nextUrlTitle;

    $('#image').load(path, function() {
        picturefill();
        prevUrlTitle = $('#prev-url-title').val();
        nextUrlTitle = $('#next-url-title').val();
        var pathPrev = '/portfolio/embed-image/'+prevUrlTitle;
        var pathNext = '/portfolio/embed-image/'+nextUrlTitle;
        $('#hidden').load(pathNext, function() {
            alert('loaded');
        });
    });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is stored by URL "/portfolio/embed-image/'+prevUrlTitle"?

$.load() loads HTML documents only.

Comment: the URL just has a html page name, so its a html document with an image in it.

Comment: Look at the DOM structure of #hidden after the second load handler was called.

Comment: How do I check the DOM structure?

Comment: Use Firebug in FF or Developer Tools in Chome/Safary. Or Developer Toolbar in IE.